# improving php code for if statements

Tags: php, cakephp-2.0

I have this code

```
if(!array_key_exists('key1', $_POST)){
    $_POST['key1'] = null;
}
if(!array_key_exists('key_x', $_POST)){
    $_POST['key_x'] = null;
}
if(!array_key_exists('key_polar_8', $_POST)){
    $_POST['key_polar_8'] = null;
}
if(!array_key_exists('nilak', $_POST)){
    $_POST['nilak'] = null;
}
```

is it a better or shorter way to write this?

Comment: Might want to ask that over on http://codereview.stackexchange.com/

Comment: A case statement will not work as this is a boolean test.

Comment: Yeah, the functions dont return unique items, just `True` of `False`.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You could put the field names in an array, then use a loop.

```
$keys = array('key1', 'key_x', 'key_polar_8', 'nilak');
foreach($keys as $k){
    if(!array_key_exists($k, $_POST)){
       $_POST[$k] = null;
    }
}
```

Comment: This is in my opinion the cleanest and more maintainable answer.

Comment: And then make it a function, oh how obvious

Comment: Exactly my thoughts, great answer.

Comment: SO sometimes is funny. Nothing personal but a +9 on a question like this seems too much to me.

Answer (score 3):

**EDIT:**
Another creative way:
Instead of checking if `array_key_exists` every time , just find those keys with `array_diff_key` and put `null`.

```
$posted_keys = array("key1" , "key2" , "nilak");
$not_in_post = array_diff_key($posted_keys, $_POST);
foreach($not_in_post as $k)
  $_POST[$k] = null;
```

(Would like to hear you opinion about this one)

Loop is king.

```
$posted_keys = array("key1" , "key2" , "nilak");
foreach($posted_keys as $key)
{
  if(!array_key_exists($key , $_POST))
  {
   $_POST[$key] = null;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Just to offer another way, not necessarily best, but you could use array_merge like so:

```
<?php
$defaultValues = array('key1'=>null, 'key_x'=>null, 'key_polar_8'=>null, 'nilak'=>null);
$_POST = array_merge($defaultValues, $_POST);
```

http://codepad.viper-7.com/ix0KTD

Might run into small problems if your post array has numeric keys as array_merge would append numeric keys. This isn't usually an issue with $_POST though.

This also allows for any value to be set as a default value, not just null.